# nodejs express not working with https

Tags: node.js, express, https

When I run my express application with https, https request aren't handled, but http request are working correctly:

```
var https = require("https");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.get(....)
...
app.post(...)

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer({key: privateKey, cert: certificate},app).listen(443);
```

Have someone experience in using express with https

Comment: Hi Ced, did you got any further on this. At the moment I'm at this stage. Trying to work my head around this. Any hint is helpful.

Comment: here is the result when trying to connect: